# MySQL query, top ten results from data, and count what is left under it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is my query, I am getting top 15 results, and everything is okay, but there is lots of rows under top 15 and I need to gather those 
results, count them and name as "Others" on the same query. Here is the result what I am getting and query:

```
SELECT  `Person` , COUNT(  `Person` ) AS Total
FROM taxes
WHERE  `Person` IS NOT NULL 
AND  `Person` <>  ''
AND  `Date` 
BETWEEN  '2013-11-11'
AND  '2013-11-30'
GROUP BY (
 `Person`
)
ORDER BY  `Total` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Result

```
Person - Total

a ------ 66     
b ------ 44
c ------ 33
d ------ 13
e ------ 14
-----------
f ------ 10
g ------ 8
h ------ 7
```

And here is what I would like to get:

```
Person | Total
a ------ 66     
b ------ 44
c ------ 33
d ------ 13
e ------ 14
-----------
others --- 25
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is very simple in the application.

Comment: It is, but the bad fact is, I can write only one query.

Comment: You only need one query. Get aggregated values without the limit. And sum the tail in the application.

Comment: Well, I am not using it in application, it's for some kind of dashboards, and results goes straight to graphics.

Comment: If you use the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option to your `SELECT` statement, MySQL will report the total number of rows that would have been returned had no `LIMIT` been applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Union, Limit, and Offset**

SQLFiddle: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69e65/1**

```
(SELECT `Person` ,
 COUNT(`Person`) AS `Total`
 FROM taxes
 WHERE `Person` IS NOT NULL
 AND `Person` <> ''
 AND `Date` BETWEEN '2013-11-11' AND '2015-11-30'
 GROUP BY `Person`
 ORDER BY COUNT(`Person`) DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION
 (SELECT 'Other',
 sum(`Total`) AS `Total`
 FROM
 ( SELECT `Person` ,
 COUNT(`Person`) AS Total
 FROM taxes
 WHERE `Person` IS NOT NULL
 AND `Person` <> ''
 AND `Date` BETWEEN '2013-11-11' AND '2015-11-30'
 GROUP BY `Person`
 ORDER BY COUNT(`Person`) DESC 
 LIMIT 2, 18446744073709551615) AS TEMP 
 );
```

**Using @row variable**

SQLFiddle: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a61a/5**

```
set @row:=1;
select if(@row>2, 'Other', `Person`) as `Person`,
sum(`Total`) as `Total`,
@row:=@row+1 as `IgnoreColumn` 
from
(
 SELECT `Person` ,
 COUNT(`Person`) AS Total
 FROM taxes
 WHERE `Person` IS NOT NULL
 AND `Person` <> ''
 AND `Date` BETWEEN '2013-11-11' AND '2015-11-30'
 GROUP BY `Person`
 ORDER BY COUNT(`Person`) DESC
) as TEMP
group by if(@row>2, 'Other', `Person`)
order by @row;
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, that A B C D was as example, not real life results from my database.

Comment: @Ignas S So your more interested in sorting by the `Total`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, top 15 and plus one row of what is left under top 15, let's say we can name that row "Others"